# Update lookup field on updating text field

Tags: lookup, fields

I have a text and a lookup field . I want  to enter a value in the text field that going to match the lookup field. For Example I am going to enter Apple in my text field. It should update apple in my lookup field. And yes apple is  already a lookup list value!
I just want to show same field in text and lookup. Process builder does not allow me to match text and lookup field.

Comment: Do you mean "picklist" rather than "lookup"? Lookup fields are connections to other Salesforce objects, and they don't accept text values.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is incorrect. You can set a picklist to a text using process builder.

Before starting: [Make sure your picklist **does not** strictly enforce it's values.](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_restricted_picklists.htm)

Then, in your process builder, select your picklist value to update it and selected **Field Reference** for the **type** and then select your field:

[image: Process Builder Sample]

In this instance, we're translating the text name into a picklist name.

That being said, I challenge your use case. This seems very likely to cause some data integrity issues and reporting problems. What ever it is you're trying to do, there's probably a better solution.

Comment: So I have a text field and I am going to enter the value in the text field which is one of the value in the lookup field. The when I enter the text field , that should just match the value which is in the lookup field

Comment: Look-up fields relate to another object. Is that what you're doing? Or are you using a picklist field? If you're using a look-up field you definitely DONT want that functionality. If you're using a picklist field, you don't want that functionality either, but it's easier to do and can be done via a PB.

Comment: Yes my lookup is related to another object . I just want to enter the values in the text . Those values will be the values in the object to which lookup field is related to . And I want to match text field with the lookup

Comment: That becomes a much much more complicated question and the simple answer is, no you don't want that. The issue is that there could be more than 1 record with the same name and your system would have no idea which record to use. The Salesforce UI already provides an accurate way to look up related records by name and select the desired record. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_searchlayout.htm&type=5 and https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_lookup_cex.htm&type=5

Comment: I added another answer  (as this answer above may still be able to help some people). If you like the answer, please go accept it so that people know what answer you chose.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, don't do that.

The issue is that there could be more than 1 record with the same name and your system would have no idea which record to use. The Salesforce UI already provides an accurate way to look up related records by name and select the desired record. [Customize Search Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_searchlayout.htm&type=5) and [Searching in look-up fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_lookup_cex.htm&type=5)

Answer (score -2):

You will need a VF Page and Javascript in order to do this. It cant be achieved through process builder. 
On tab of the text field, you can populate the Lookup field.

Thanks!

Comment: This would be true if it were actually a lookup and not a pick list field (poster just used the wrong field type in their question). Even still, if it were actually a look-up and you were using Visualforce, you wouldn't need JS as they would be able to directly bind the field to the page and SF would provide the look-up icon for them and there'd be no need for a second text field.